# Improve lookup of 1.5 million rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, pgadmin, postgresql-performance

I have this table with data but we need to get all the (unique) `rdx` and `rdy` values:

```
CREATE TABLE public.positions
(
  datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  unitid bigint NOT NULL,
  rdx double precision NOT NULL,
  rdy double precision NOT NULL,
  speed integer NOT NULL,
  course integer NOT NULL,
  numsatallites integer NOT NULL,
  hdop integer NOT NULL,
  quality character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT positions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (datetime, unitid),
  CONSTRAINT car_fkey_positions FOREIGN KEY (unitid)
      REFERENCES public.car (unitid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

Create index rdx_index on Positions (rdx,rdy);
```

We tried this query:

```
SELECT rdx,rdy 
FROM Positions 
GROUP BY rdx,rdy
```

But the Query is taking to long (30seconds+).

I have tried to use explain but it doesn't use an index.

How can we speed this query up?

Or is there no possible way because we need to retrieve nearly all the data from the table.

PostgreSQL version: 9.5

Output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`:

```
Group  (cost=0.43..106482.35 rows=134251 width=16) (actual time=0.044..819.760 rows=995461 loops=1)"
 Group Key: rdx, rdy"
 Buffers: shared hit=971840 read=5464"
   ->  Index Only Scan using rdx_index on positions  (cost=0.43..99769.81 rows=1342509 width=16) (actual time=0.039..597.593 rows=1342509 loops=1)"
        Heap Fetches: 1342509"
       Buffers: shared hit=971840 read=5464"
Planning time: 0.183 ms"
Execution time: 840.152 ms"
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question and add the complete `create table` statement including all `create index` statements for that table. Add formatted **text** don't post screenshots. And add the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)` (again as formatted text, no screenshots). And add the exact Postgres version you are using.

Comment: edited see question for update

Comment: That is only the output of `explain`, not the output of `explain (analyze, buffers)`

Comment: updated the question!

Comment: The query runs for less than a second (850ms). I guess the 30seconds you experience are the overhead of _displaying_  the rows in the SQL client.

Comment: I feel, so stupid right now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name isn't the number of buffers hit a bit too high for this many rows?

Comment: @dezso: indeed it is. That could indicate index bloat. But that is not related to the original question "why does it take 30 seconds?"

Comment: @dezso If none of the table is marked all-visible, than it has to hit the heap block for ever index row.  Now, it will be hitting the same blocks over and over, but they still count separately.

Comment: @jjanes that sounds very ineffective - way more so than a sequential scan.  Are you sure about this?

Comment: @dezso  I'm sure that is what it does.  Why it chooses to do an index only scan in the first place, I don't know.  Either the stats are bad and it thinks it is mostly marked all-visible even though it is not, or it really really wants to avoid a sort or a hashagg (work_mem set very low?)

Comment: @jjanes AFAIK the `work_mem` setting does not influence the planner.

Comment: @dezso  The planner will discourage/forbid hashagg when it thinks it will not fit in work_mem.  I don't know if it also discourages sorts when it thinks they will spill to disk, so the trade-off between sorting and walking the index perhaps doesn't depend on work_mem